# How do I include a virtual env in a linux package (.deb or .pkg.tar.zst)?

Tags: python, linux, virtualenv

I want to package an app written in python. For python packages I might have added `python-packagename` to dependencies. But the problem is, the app depends on older versions of python packages and also requires `python3.8`. Can I include a virtual environment in the package that is configured for `python3.8` and already have required packages installed? Or can I create a virtual environment just after installation without asking the user to manually configure it?

Answer (score 0):

It would be helpful if you included the Linux distribution you're trying to package your application for in your question. Given the title, I'm going to assume that you are packaging for Ubuntu/Debian (please correct me if I'm wrong).

In general it is possible to specify specific versions of third-party packages as dependencies to the package you're creating, so you should be able to declare that your package is dependent on python3.8. That said, the details of how to package applications/libraries written using a certain language/framework and what are the best practices to do that vary based on the language and Linux distribution, so you're always better off making a quick search on the Web based on your particular needs. Often this will result in useful tutorials, and sometimes (e.g. in the case of Debian and derivatives or Arch Linux), packaging guidelines. This is indeed the case for Debian: https://opensource.com/article/20/4/package-python-applications-linux and https://wiki.debian.org/Python/LibraryStyleGuide. These two resources should get you started.

Comment: I want to create package both for debian and arch. This probably works on debain (although I haven't tested). But I also need a solution for arch (I googled but didn't find anything `:(`).

Comment: Arch wiki is your friend :) https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Python_package_guidelines

Answer (score 0):

The `pip` package contains a folder `_vendor` with dependencies.
I don't know what's the best way to install dependencies in such a non-standard place, though.

See https://github.com/pypa/pip/tree/d35bedc5cbb9f19217f6a42a68ab3c7f010fe694/src/pip